# angular2 + selenium webdriver: Can't resolve 'child_process

Tags: angularjs, selenium, typescript

I did this:

```
ng new typescript-selenium-example
npm install selenium-webdriver --save
```

(in addition I have copied `chromedriver` to my `/Application`)

update `app.component.ts` to be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Builder, By, until } from 'selenium-webdriver';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    var driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

    driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr')
        .then(_ => driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver'))
        .then(_ => driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click())
        .then(_ => driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000))
        .then(_ => driver.quit());
    console.log('hi');
  }
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

getting erros:

```
ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/myname/tmp/typescript-selenium-example/node_modules/sele
nium-webdriver/net'
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js 20:11-35
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/myname/tmp/typescript-selenium-example/node_modules/sele
nium-webdriver/firefox'
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js 25:14-38
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/myname/tmp/typescript-selenium-example/node_modules/sele
nium-webdriver/io'
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js 20:21-45
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

Answer (score 34):

This problem showed up for me also when one of my tests had a bad `beforeEach` method in it.  The function was trying to reach a global variable in the function before it was initialized.  Maybe that will help you?

As the comments point out, this can also happen when you have a bad import, such as:

```
import {describe} from 'selenium-webdriver';
```

or

```
import {beforeEach} from "selenium-webdriver/testing";
```

Comment: oh I long out of this one, if i get back to it i'll try your suggestion voted it up.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I commented out my last set of tests I modified, and sure enough, everything started working again. @Jas if you get a chance, you should accept this as the answer.

Comment: specifically, just found out it's because Webstorm automatically added `import {describe} from 'selenium-webdriver';` based on a typo I made. That causes selinium to spaz. Removing the errant import fixes the problem for me.

Comment: had the exact same problem.  Had the following dodgy import... `import {beforeEach} from "selenium-webdriver/testing";`

Comment: import { promise } from 'selenium-webdriver'   --- thanks for the 2 hours lost IntelliJ.

Answer (score 25):

For me I had accidentally imported the wrong library within a component.

I changed this:

`import { EventEmitter } from 'selenium-webdriver';`

into this:

`import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

and it works again.

Comment: Yes! That's it!

Comment: Darn auto import!

Comment: Thanks for this.