# Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' Angular-cli

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium-webdriver, angular-cli

I generated a new application using angular-cli and added few components. I haven't added any test cases. when I try to run/build the app, I get the following lengthy error message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/myName/PROJECTS/MEAN/fruit-stall/fruitStall/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
resolve 'child_process' in '/home/myName/PROJECTS/MEAN/fruit-stall/fruitStall/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/myName/PROJECTS/MEAN/fruit-stall/fruitStall/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/package.json (relative path: ./firefox)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /home/myName/PROJECTS/MEAN/fruit-stall/fruitStall/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/package.json (relative path: ./firefox)
    resolve as module
      /home/myName/PROJECTS/MEAN/fruit-stall/fruitStall/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/myName/PROJECTS/MEAN/fruit-stall/fruitStall/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/myName/PROJECTS/MEAN/fruit-stall/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/myName/PROJECTS/MEAN/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/myName/PROJECTS/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/myName/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /home/myName/PROJECTS/MEAN/fruit-stall/fruitStall/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/node_modules
        using description file: /home/myName/PROJECTS/MEAN/fruit-stall/fruitStall/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
```

Please find the detailed dump [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gLw8iQ3_H4x6iDmT3BYOUlGpTPpggkAjbyiPKbb4Z5U/edit?usp=sharing).

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Angular version is: 5.0.2
node: 9.2.0

I also found a similar question being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057396/angular2-selenium-webdriver-cant-resolve-child-process), but it is related to the test cases. Since I haven't written any test cases, that did not help me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Got the culprit!

I was adding some events to one of the component and visual studio code imported event emitter from selenium instead of angular-core.

deleted this

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'selenium-webdriver';
```

and updated this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Thank you! :D It was the EventEmitter from protractor for me.

Comment: Me too. It was from `protractor`. And why was that heppened?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't have too much context here since you just posted errors, but this could be similar to [Webpack and TypeScript: Cannot resolve module 'child_process' in node.d.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000827/webpack-and-typescript-cannot-resolve-module-child-process-in-node-d-ts).

Adding `"target": "node"` to your webpack configs could resolve the issue.

Comment: Since my project is generated using angular-cli, I do not have webpack.config.js file.

Comment: u can use **ng eject** in cli

Comment: The 'eject' command has been disabled and will be removed completely in 8.0.
The new configuration format provides increased flexibility to modify the configuration of your workspace without ejecting.

There are several projects that can be used in conjuction with the new configuration format that provide the benefits of ejecting without the maintenance overhead.  One such project is ngx-build-plus found here:
https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus